# Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException : Schema-Tool failed with tests

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony

I use a Docker, Symfony and Postgres to development my Symfony app:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libpq-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql

# Configure non-root user.
ARG PUID=1000
ARG PGID=1000
RUN apk --no-cache add shadow && \
    groupmod -o -g ${PGID} www-data && \
    usermod -o -u ${PUID} -g www-data www-data

# Source code
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./ /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

USER www-data
```

and i want to use [LiipTestFixturesBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle) to load fixtures in my database

```
  public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        self::bootKernel();

        $container = static::getContainer();
        $this->repository = $container->get(TemplateRepository::class);
        $this->databaseTool = $container->get(DatabaseToolCollection::class)->get();
        $this->databaseTool->loadFixtures([
            TemplateFixture::class]);
    }
```

But when i try to run my tests i get an error

```
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException : Schema-Tool failed with Error 'An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE templates (id UUID NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) ...
                     ^' while executing DDL: CREATE TABLE templates (id UUID NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

I have 2 databases - teambox and teambox_test (as expected in `doctrine.yaml`)

```
when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:    
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'
```

[image]

`packages/test/liip_test_fixture.yaml`

```
liip_test_fixtures:
  keep_database_and_schema: true
  cache_metadata: true
  cache_db: ~
```